# Longtable displays extra cells in html output

Tags: longtable, tex4ht, htlatex

In HTML, my table has extra cells below the header row and below the left hand cell on the bottom row.

```
\begin{longtable}{ | p{2.0cm} | *{5}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm} |} } 
\hline
\b{Columnhead} & \b{Columnhead} & \b{Columnhead} & \b{Columnhead} &
\b{Columnhead}\\ 
\hline \endhead

Cell &

Cell \newline
Line \newline
Line \newline
Line - line n &

Cell &

Cell &

Cell \\

\hline

Cell &

Cell \newline
Line \newline
Line \newline
Line - line n &

Cell &

Cell &

Cell \\

\hline
\end{longtable}
```

[image: misplaced cells]

Comment: The PDF output displays well. I dont understand these tables enough to troubleshoot the problem. It seems that the first value in the header row definition (p{2.0cm}) ensures that there is a right hand margin. and the other value in that line defines the width fo the columns (p{3.5cm}).

Comment: By "in HTML", do you mean "when processed with tex4ht"? If so, there is a known bug in connection with longtable: https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?196 which you may be hitting. Perhaps one of the developers will weigh in.

Comment: @AlexWatson Yes it turns out that tex4ht is used. 
Any ideas on a better way to format my tables?
I had for requirements for my table formatting: allow headers for long tables to carry over pages in PDF output, left align content with ragged edges and have multiple lines in table cells, grid lines.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't post a complete `mwe`, so I've constructed one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\begin{document}
some text before 
\begin{longtable}{ | p{2.0cm} | *{4}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.5cm} |} } 
\hline
\b{Columnhead} & \b{Columnhead} & \b{Columnhead} & \b{Columnhead} &
\b{Columnhead}  \\ 
\hline \endhead

Cell &

Cell \newline
Line \newline
Line \newline
Line - line n &

Cell &

Cell &

Cell \\

\hline

Cell &

Cell \newline
Line \newline
Line \newline
Line - line n &

Cell &

Cell &

Cell \\

\hline
\end{longtable}

misplaced cells
\end{document}
```

I would say that the extra column is caused by the fact that you define 6 columns in your sample, but then use only 5 columns in each row. As `tex4ht` uses CSS for drawing of the borders, it draws border also around this empty column.

To remove the empty rows, you can use a `make4ht` build file. Save the following code as `build.lua`:

```lua
local domfilter = require "make4ht-domfilter"

local process = domfilter {function(dom)
  local is_empty_row = function(row)
    local not_empty = false
    local element_count = 0
    -- ignore hline rows
    local row_class = row:get_attribute("class") 
    if row_class == "hline" or row_class == "cline" then return false end
    -- detect if the row contain only one empty child
    for _,child in ipairs(row:get_children() or {}) do
      if child:is_element() then 
        element_count = element_count + 1
        -- empty rows contain only one element, it is not empty otherwise
        if element_count > 1 then return false end
        -- detect if it contains only whitespace
        not_empty = child:get_text():gsub("%s","") ~= "" or not_empty
      end
    end
    -- print("element count", element_count, not_empty)
    return element_count == 1 and not_empty == false
  end
  for _, tbl in ipairs(dom:query_selector("table")) do
    -- find the empty rows
    for _, row in ipairs(tbl:query_selector("tr")) do
      if is_empty_row(row) then row:remove_node() end
    end

  end
  return dom
end}

Make:match("html$", process)
```

It uses LuaXML library to process all `<table>` elements and to remove all empty rows from tables.

One additional fix I would use is to correct rendering of the horizontal lines. Try this `mycfg.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{tr.hline, tr.hline td, tr.cline, tr.cline td{padding:0;}}
\Css{tr.hline hr, tr.cline hr{border:none;border-top:1px solid black;}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Compile with

```
make4ht -c mycfg.cfg -e build.lua filename.tex
```

This is the result:

[image]